# Is it possible to have a Java program and a Rest client access a Neo4J database

Tags: neo4j

It is my understanding that if you are using the Java execution engine that you cannot also have the neo4j process up that allows you to access the DB through the web console.  But this same process is what facilitates the REST API, correct?  Is there a way to utilize the execution engine through a Java program AND the REST API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the main issue as I understand it is that only one JVM process can access the database at a time.   So when you talk about the REST API, what you really mean is that there is a [neo4j server](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-installation.html) running.  That JVM process has locked the database.  And that server instance happens to provide a REST API on some host and port.   Now, if you've got a server instance running, you can't separately run a different java process that accesses the same database using an [embedded database](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-java-embedded.html).

To do what you want, you have two options:

**Option 1:  Use REST from Java**

You can write a java program that [uses the REST interface](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-java-rest-client-example.html).  In this case, your second java program is just making network calls to the server, and is not touching the database directly itself.  So no conflict, you can do both.

Your code will look different - it will be more focused on issuing RESTful calls and processing the resulting JSON, like this:

```
final String txUri = SERVER_ROOT_URI + "transaction/commit";
WebResource resource = Client.create().resource( txUri );

String payload = "{\"statements\" : [ {\"statement\" : \"" +query + "\"} ]}";
ClientResponse response = resource
        .accept( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
        .type( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
        .entity( payload )
        .post( ClientResponse.class );

System.out.println( String.format(
        "POST [%s] to [%s], status code [%d], returned data: "
                + System.getProperty( "line.separator" ) + "%s",
        payload, txUri, response.getStatus(),
        response.getEntity( String.class ) ) );

response.close();
```

See earlier links for more code examples and tutorials.

**Option 2:  Use GraphDatabaseService wrapper**

There's the [GraphDatabaseService](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/java-rest-binding) wrapper.   That lets you do this:

```
GraphDatabaseService gds = new RestGraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data");
```

You can then use the `gds` object much like you would use a regular Java API object.

This works for the same reason option 1 does - you're not hitting the database directly, but just interacting with the RESTful services through a wrapper.